# How To Fetch Webpage Source simultaneously from thousands of URLs

Tags: vb.net, webclient

I am attempting to load thousands of URLs into a list, then simultaneously download the webpage source of all of those URLs. I thought I had a clear understanding of how to accomplish this but it seems that the process goes 1 by 1 (which is painstakingly slow).

Is there a way to make this launch all of these URLs at once, or perhaps more than 1 at a time?

```
Public Partial Class MainForm

Dim ImportList As New ListBox
Dim URLList As String
Dim X1 As Integer
Dim CurIndex As Integer

Public Sub New()
    Me.InitializeComponent()
End Sub

Sub MainFormLoad(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Try
        Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\URLFile.txt")
        ImportList.Items.AddRange(lines)    
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    Finally
        label1.Text = "File Loaded" 
        X1 = ImportList.Items.Count
        timer1.Enabled = True
        If Not backgroundWorker1.IsBusy Then
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
        End If
    End Try
End Sub

Sub BackgroundWorker1DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
    URLList = ""
    For Each item As String In ImportList.Items
        CheckName(item)
        CurIndex = CurIndex + 1
    Next
End Sub

Sub BW1_Completed()
    timer1.Enabled = False
    label1.Text = "Done"
End Sub

Sub CheckName(ByVal CurUrl As String)
    Dim RawText As String
    Try
        RawText = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(CurUrl)         
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    Finally
        If RawText.Contains("404") Then
            If URLList = "" Then
                URLList = CurUrl
            Else
                URLList = URLList & vbCrLf & CurUrl
            End If
        End If
    End Try
End Sub

Sub Timer1Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    label1.Text = CurIndex.ToString & " of " & X1.ToString
    If Not URLList = "" Then
        textBox1.Text = URLList
    End If
End Sub

Sub Button1Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Clipboard.Clear
    Clipboard.SetText(URLList)
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: You could put the loop to iterate ImportList.Items in your MainformLoad, then create a new background worker instance inside that loop to process the current item.  Wil maybe need to consider too many concurrent threads though

Comment: This was my next plan and I had done this prior to your post. However, it seems to be a limitation of webclient that that it cannot hold more than one session at a time.

Comment: Maybe try HttpClient instead of WebClient then.  Been a while since I've used web client but from memory it did have some limitations that HttpClient handles better